# error while connecting to other function using connect while using pyqtlet in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, leaflet, pyqt5, pyqtlet

Error:
QObject::connect: Cannot connect Map::clicked(PyQt_PyObject) to (nullptr)::save(PyQt_PyObject)

Not able to call method save using connect.
I basically want to save the coordinates when the user clicks a position on map. so i call the method save if the user clicks anywhere on map and save it in variable a
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from pyqtlet import L, MapWidget
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1256, 744)
        self.mapWidget = MapWidget()
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 0, 631, 541))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.mapWidget)
        self.map = L.map(self.mapWidget)
        self.map.setView([12.97, 77.59], 10)
        self.map.clicked.connect(self.save)
        
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(self.map)
        self.marker = L.marker([12.934056, 77.610029])
        self.marker.bindPopup('Maps are a treasure.')
        self.map.addLayer(self.marker)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(620, 560, 81, 31))
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(730, 560, 91, 31))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1256, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menufile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menufile.setObjectName("menufile")
        self.menuload = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menufile)
        self.menuload.setObjectName("menuload")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionnew = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionnew.setObjectName("actionnew")
        self.actionnull = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionnull.setObjectName("actionnull")
        self.menuload.addAction(self.actionnull)
        self.menufile.addAction(self.actionnew)
        self.menufile.addAction(self.menuload.menuAction())
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menufile.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "start"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "done"))
        self.menufile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "file"))
        self.menuload.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "load"))
        self.actionnew.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "new"))
        self.actionnull.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "null"))
        
    @pyqtSlot(dict)
    def save(self, path):
        self.a=path
        print(self.a['latlng']['lat'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QtDesigner changes will be lost after redesign User Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46544780/qtdesigner-changes-will-be-lost-after-redesign-user-interface)

Comment: This is partially related to [Connecting a signal to slot yields (nullptr)::slot() error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62291092/2001654), and mostly caused by the fact that you're using a slot (which can only be properly used for QObject subclasses) on a basic python class. You're editing a pyuic file, which is considered a *bad* practice for many reasons (including this one). Please regenerate the file and follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to properly implement your program.